# Java ResourceBundle leading whitespace in values

Tags: java, whitespace, resourcebundle

I'm trying out the example given at [Oracle's documentations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html). The java file is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/examples/PropertiesDemo.java) as shown in that page. Now with this java file, I keep a `LabelsBundle.properties` file in the same directory.

```
# This is the default LabelsBundle.properties file
s1 = computer
s2 = disk
s3 = monitor
s4 = keyboard
```

it seems that the trailing whitespace is not ignored while reading the values and the leading whitespaces are ignored.

So if I want leading spaces to be there, what do I do?

In other words, what do I need to do to read the value of `s1` as

```
 computer
```

instead of

```
computer
```

?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A Unicode escape sequence `\u0020` should do it, because the properties parser should recognise it as an actual value and the Java String should interpret `\u0020` as the Unicode code point for space.

Alternatively, IIRC, you can escape the space with a backslash like this `\ my value`. Works for keys, too.

Comment: \u0020 would work without any encoding change?

and @Zaki: I tried and without changing any encoding, `\` worked !?

Comment: Yes, because `\u0020` is code. In fact, this is what the native2ascii tool does: convert all characters outside the ASCII range to such Unicode escape sequences to ensure the properties file loads properly without breaking characters when the properties code itself is treated as ASCII.

Comment: also, can I do it without changing the properties file? In java code I mean?

Comment: If you mean, configuring the Properties parser to not strip leading whitespace then no. Unless you roll your own and use that, but to me that seems way more effort than editing the properties file and rather pointless.

Answer (score 20):

You can escape space with backlash:

```
s1 =\ computer
```

Comment: also, can I do it without changing the properties file? In java code I mean?