# How to add a space in prefix and suffix of the value in application.properties file in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

Spring Boot application does not consider a space in prefix or suffix in the value for a key in application.properties file.

Both of the following are same for the Spring Boot:

- app.my-key=[space]my value[space]
- app.my-key=my value

I tried enclosing the value in single quote and double quotes as follows but it doesn't work:

- app.my-key=' my value '
- app.my-key=" my value "

Comment: I would say that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783523/java-resourcebundle-leading-whitespace-in-values is a duplicate for this.